# Recolor an image using fabric js filters

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to use tint filter on some images in canvas, it works great with white images but not with colored ones, it keeps the original color of the image and apply the tint color on top of it, so it gives the wrong color.

Found out later that maybe I'm misunderstanding the tint filter concept and that it's not meant to recolor the image, so is there any way using fabric filters to recolor images ?

[image-here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVcwT.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What exactly are you trying to do? IE: use a b&w filter, sepia, etc?

Comment: @Jacques i'm working on a t-shirt customization and i'm trying to recolor images after adding them to the canvas to let the users choose which color they which to use, the problem here is that the tint filter can't recolor the image, it only add color to the image so if the image isn't white the result color isn't the same as the chosen one

Comment: So you're trying to change the color of the shirt? Have you thought of just using a background image (svg) of the shirt, and changing the color in the svg? However, if you're trying to change the color of photos, for instance, what you want is a tint or "overlay" of a the effects that fabric gives you. The only way to make the color match, is if the image you're recoloring loses it's details. Think of it it like using an "overlay" in photoshop. You keep the photo details and, except on white, the color doesn't match, but if you used the color solid instead of overlay, you'd lose the details

Comment: i'm sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough, I have no problem with changing the t-shirt color.
I have added a link to an image describing what I'm trying to do, I applied the same color to the little decoration in the two first images at the left and the results at the right

Comment: That is something you cannot do in fabric, however you may be able to pull it off with SVG

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thanks for you time

Comment: you can do in fabric, but you have to explain your source images. you can do both with svg and normal images, you may need a hue rotation or even tint filter may be good if you start from a grey scale image. post some picture please.